# JavaFX Mouse Coordinates

Tags: events, javafx, mouseevent, coordinates

how can i get the exact Mouse-Position in JavaFX?

I can add a Mouse-Event on a Button like this:

```
btnTriangle.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent me)
            {
                //I NEED TO GET THE X and Y Coordinates from the Mouse
            }
        });
```

I need the X and Y Value to show there some special Content...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Get them from the [`MouseEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to add 2 lines in your code to get them as James_D said:

```
btnTriangle.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
            System.out.println("Coordinate X -> " + me.getX());
            System.out.println("Coordinate Y -> " + me.getY());
        }
    });
```